# How to edit stylesheet location

Tags: magento-1, css, theme-fallback

I am trying to experiment creating a magento theme. I copied the base files and put them into my theme. What file can you change the path in a header meta tag for a stylesheet for example.

This is because my style-sheet currently points to:

`skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css`

but the theme needs changing in that tag.

Answer (score 1):

**To activate your theme**, you will need to declare it in `system > configuration > design`. Then magento will start looking files accordingly.

**To point css to your theme**, you will have to do this from your `layout` files.

## Example

Open `rwd/default/layout/page.xml` and have a look something similar to this.

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name</action>
```

Here we are asking magento to look `styles.css` in `skin` folder.

`<type>skin_css</type>` means `styles.css` file is located inside the `skin`.

Magento has fallback function in place, if you have declared `rwd` as a base theme in `system > config > design` section, it will try to find the `styles.css` inside `frontend/rwd/default/css`, and if not found then it will look into `frontend/base/default/css` folder (falling back to base theme).

You can also set `parent / child` theme in magento.

[More reading](http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need change to meta tag

Go to `admin >> system >> design >>`

and set the current theme which you are created.. and also refresh the cache too..

also follow this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/magento-theme-development-an-introduction--cms-21036)  for how to create a theme.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets can either be called upon through an XML file or PHTML file.

Using an XML file:

```
<layout>
 <default>
   <reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>styles.css</name></action>
   </reference>
 </default>
</layout>
```

You might want to experiment with your local.xml